# Are child processes supposed to execute slower than parent processes?

Tags: c, fork, parent-child

I have a program in C that takes numbers from a file and subtracts them, but I use the fork system call right before the process executes, and I use the clock() function right after fork to measure the execution time of the parent and child. I was told that the child process always works slower than the parent process, but this has only been true so far for file sizes smaller than a certain size. Can someone explain if child processes really are supposed to work slower than parent processes? I don't understand why this would be true if a child and parent uses the same information.

Comment: Please show the code related to your testing methodology. There are no guarantees on either the child nor the parent running slower, unless they somehow synchronize around a common resource (such as a mutex in shared memory, a pipe, etc) and that synchronization imposes a constraint that one finishes before the other.

Answer (score 0):

Although Forking is handled differently on different systems, it has no effect on the scheduling in all operating systems I know.

It is possible to give parent and child different priorities and that is definitely common, especially for real-time environments. But that does not happen by default.

I don't know what your code does and I don't know how you measured the execution time, but I'd rather assume the problem in one of those.